# URL Rewrite in IIS 7.5

Tags: url-rewriting, seo

I have a web site (hosted on IIS 7.5) that has bindings to four URLs. Something like:

1. www.example.com
2. example.com
3. www.example.net
4. example.net

What I would like to accomplish using URL Rewrite is that:

1. Surfing to www.example.com will auto redirect to example.com (and return 301)
2. Surfing to example.net will auto redirect to www.example.net (and return 301)

I tried using the  URL Rewrite (I have no experience using this feature) using the IIS MANAGER > FEATURES > URL Rewrite > Add Rule > canonical domain name, but the problem is that then I can choose one address of those four, that will cause all the other three to be redirected to that, which is not what I need to do.

Can you please help and advise? Is URL Rewrite is a good and possible way to do this?

Comment: Any ideas, someone?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

Add the following rules to the web config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect domain 1">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Redirect domain 2">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.net$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.net/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```